# How do i make an html text area appear javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Basically - I want a `<textarea>`, but when people type things into it, for example - `const item = require('item')`, I want the `const` to appear purple, like JavaScript editors.

Comment: that's not possible with a standard textarea.

Comment: You will need to use something like https://highlightjs.org/ . a standard textarea cannot handle this.

Comment: Maybe take a look at Vue.js? If I understood your question correctly, you want to highlight some text on "live" mode? Vue.js might help you with that - it is the easiest way I can think of right now. Or use already created JS libraries, like prims.js or highlight.js

Answer (score 0):

You need a JS code editor library for that as it is not possible with a normal textarea and some JS. (And [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) as suggested by Ritesh wont work because it is not for live input) So here are some good libraries you can use for live syntax highlighting:

Editors with a lot of great features:

[CodeMirror](https://codemirror.net/)

[Ace](https://ace.c9.io/)

Some smaller ones:

[CodeJar](https://medv.io/codejar/)

[CodeFlask](https://kazzkiq.github.io/CodeFlask/)

And absolute overkill:

[Monaco](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/)

I hope, I could help you. Have a nice day :)

Comment: *it is not possible with a normal textarea* yes it is. OP might have to write some actual code but you don't **have** to use a third party library

Comment: @Liam Yea, kinda... The most used way to do that is to make the actual textarea invisible and you use the text from it to generate the html code for the text highlighting exactly behind it. I just meant, that you need more than a textarea - sorry if that wasn't clear.